# Any way to get flow status (maybe like, running, stopped, stopped with exception) with spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Recently, I was trying to build a rest service to create, start and stop an integration flow (which was reading an RSS feed and printing on console), and I was able to achieve that.

But my next requirement was to get status (maybe like, running, stopped, stopped with exception) from the already running flow, and I was unable to do that, I cannot see any method related to that in "IntegrationFlowRegistration".

Also, is there a way to store "IntegrationFlow" in RDBMS like MySql, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the flow by itself is just a logical container for components it connects. Even though we really can get somehow access to all those components in one `IntegrationFlow`, that doesn't mean that your whole solution contains only one `IntegrationFlow`. It is fully normal to connect components from different `IntegrationFlow`s since at runtime they are fully not related to the `IntegrationFlow` created them. Those runtime components are identical after any configuration parsing we have in the framework: XML, Java DSL, Kotlin DSL or just plain Java & Annotation configuration. You even can create all the beans manually and still at runtime it is going to be an EIP solution.

What I'm trying to say that it is wrong to try to find a solution for the whole flow state. Or you should consult some individual component (e.g. the mentioned RSS one), or you should have some separate component to track such a custom state.

See `Lifecycle` contract. Most of Spring Integration implements it, so you can check its `isRunning()` whenever you need. In fact even a `StandardIntegrationFlow` implement this one, but you should not fully rely on it because your final solution might consist from several flows or many independent components.

There is no anything like `stopped with exception` - we don't stop components because of an error. Instead you can enable metrics and check channel or handlers `success` and `failure` send counts: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#metrics-management

Comment: Artem, I have also asked a question i.e "Also, is there a way to store "IntegrationFlow" in RDBMS like MySql, etc?", I mean to store integration flow like a serialized object or anything else,  any suggestions on that?

Comment: IntegrationFlowContext.IntegationFlowRegistration already has start and stop mapped from Lifecycle. Adding also isRunning would be nice. Anyway the fact that IntegrationFlow s get erased at runtime does not feels right.

Comment: No, there is no way to serialize an `IntegrationFlow` into external store since it is a live object with reference to many other beans in the application context. We would need to have the whole beans tree to be serializable but that is not so easy. There is probably a way to keep the flow in the XML format, so then we can store it as a plain text and then use a `GenericXmlApplicationContext` to create a child application context based on that XML definition.

Comment: You don't need to worry about lifecycle on the `IntegrationFlowContext.IntegationFlowRegistration`. It is just a registration phase pointer. The real object you need to deal with is an `IntegrationFlow` bean added into the application context. Its `StandardIntegrationFlow` implementation has the mentioned `isRunning()` contract.

Comment: We remove the dynamic flow from the application context and from the memory only when you ask to do that via `IntegrationFlowRegistration.destroy()`.